# Turn off confirmation on setting breakpoint in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Setting breakpoint on shared library:

```
(gdb) b file.c:278
 No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
 Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
```

Can I make gdb not to ask this question? (that, is, skip confirmation?)

Comment: Try `set confirm off`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "help set breakpoint pending", or "apropos pending".

Comment: set breakpoint pending on